# What's the type match here?

Tags: excel, vba, types, match, rename

When the code compiles, it highlights "rs.Range" as a TypeMatch error. I can't figure out why-- I don't think I set anything as a number instead of a string....

```
Dim rs As Worksheet
Dim MonthYear As String
Dim Month() As String
  
  MonthYear = Range("N1")
  Month = Split(MonthYear, ";")


For Each rs In Sheets
rs.Name = rs.Range("O2") & "(" & Month & ")"
Next rs
```

What this should do -- I hope -- is take the currency in column O and the name of the month in the header of column N and name the sheet accordingly, like so:

N: Jan-22

O: ILS

intended sheet name: ILS (Jan)

Comment: When asking a code-related question, the very first tag you add should be for the language you're using. It helps get the question in front of the people who can answer it, as well as help future site users find it in a search. Please [edit] to add that tag now.

Comment: Sorry! Noob mistake!

Comment: `Month` is an array. You are concatenating it with a string.

Comment: In addition to what @GSerg said, you're also trying to split on `;`, which does not exist in your month-year value. Split on `-` instead, and then use the first element of the array.

Comment: You also say your intended sheet name id `ILS (Jan)` with a space.  Your code doesn't inclide that

Comment: Thanks, everyone!
The space is the least of my worries at the moment : ) That will be " (", won't it?

So I should write

Dim Month () as Array

and

Month = Split(MonthYear, "-")

?